# Как поместить курсор в конец строки, которую вставил? | JS

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Как мне поместить курсор в конец СТРОКИ которую ТОЛЬКО ЧТО ВСТАВИЛ. Я знаю, как поместить курсор в конец contenteditable, но как сделать это с определенным отрезком строки?

К примеру, при onPaste я заменяю ссылку на тэг `<x-link class="input__link" data-target="link">link</x-link>` и так получается, что курсор остается внутри тэга, поэтому любой дальнейший текст расценивается как ссылка. Как мне поместить крусор в конец тэга?

```
</x-link>| <---сюда
```

**Пример такой строки:**

`Тестовая документация по инпуту находится <x-link class="input__link" data-target="link">тут(<--- а он тут)</x-link>(<--- сюда надо курсор поставить), а не <x-link class="input__link" data-target="link">тут</x-link>`

Comment: Речь идёт о [каретке](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80) или о курсоре в целом, если второе - то курсор двигать нельзя.

Comment: @De.Minov, о каретке